# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: string, syntax, integer, python-3.7

I am creating a Vending Machine as part of a checkpoint test but I am facing a recurring problem stated below.

I'm using Python 3.7.4

```
print("----WELCOME TO THE ABBEY GRANGE VENDING MACHINE----")
print("Please enter three coins")

first = input("Please enter your first coin: ")
first = int(first)

second = input("Please enter your second coin: ")
second = int(second)

third = input("Please enter your third coin: ")
third = int(third)

coin = int(first) + int(second) + int(third)
coin= int(coin)

if int(coin >= "15"):
    print("Thank you! You have inserted", money,"pence")
else:
    print("You have not inserted enough coins. You may not purchase anything at this time!")`
    print("Goodbye")`
```

The code continues with the same problem:

```
print("Or we can pick something for you but you must have over 65p")

if money > "65":
    choice = input("Would you like a generated option? ")
    if choice == "Yes":
       print (menu)
```

If the user inputs 10, 10, 10 for the first number as it is greater than 15, I'd expect the code to carry on but instead, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\Downloads\Abbey Grange Vending Machine.py", line 21, in <module>
    if int(coin >= "15"):
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: python is telling you exactly where the (first) error is. It should be `coin>=15`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform a logical operation/comparison between two variables of different data-types `int` and `str` for your case.
Your also passing the `money variable` to a `print` function yet it's not defined anywhere in your code.
The code below fixes your problem

```
print("----WELCOME TO THE ABBEY GRANGE VENDING MACHINE----")
print("Please enter three coins")

first = input("Please enter your first coin: ")
first = int(first)

second = input("Please enter your second coin: ")
second = int(second)

third = input("Please enter your third coin: ")
third = int(third)

coin = first + second + third

if (coin >= 15):
    print(f"Thank you! You have inserted, {coin} pence")
else:
    print("You have not inserted enough coins. You may not purchase anything at this time!")
    print("Goodbye")
```